# Condicionar acesso ao próximo form através de inputbox

Tags: vb.net

Estou a desenvolver um projeto simples em visual basic. Quando se clica no botão com a fotografia do pacman, surge uma inputbox.

Pretendia que nessa inputbox, o utilizador apenas fosse capaz de avançar para o próximo form se escrevesse "Nao sou um robo".

Já estou familiarizado com a função UCase() para aumentar as possibilidades de input, mas pretendia que não fosse possível inserir números ou conseguir avançar sem escrever nada ou algo diferente do pretendido.

O problema é, o utilizador pode inserir qualquer coisa, até números, que depois de clicar 2x Ok, avança para o próximo form independentemente do que escreva.

O código (rudimentar e provavelmente errado) que tentei no botão é este:

```
Dim input As String
input = InputBox("Para prosseguir escreva: Nao sou um robo", "Verificação de identidade",,,)
If input = "Nao sou um robo" Then
    Me.Hide()
    Form2.Show()
Else
    Do
        input = If(input.Any(Function(c) Not Char.IsLetter(c)), "", input)
    Loop While input <> UCase("Nao sou um robo") Or input = ""
End If
```

Agradecia imenso qualquer ajuda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes por este código dentro de um *loop* `While` e só permitir sair ao digitar o valor correto, e usar o `UCase` caso queira ignora maiúsculas/minúsculas:

```
Dim input As String

' Loop infinito
While True
    input = InputBox("Para prosseguir escreva: Nao sou um robo", "Verificação de identidade",,,)

    If UCase(input) = "NAO SOU UM ROBO" Then
        ' Sai do Loop
        Exit While
    End If
End While

Me.Hide()
Form2.Show()
```

Comment: Resolveu perfeitamente o problema, agradeço-lhe imenso!

Comment: não esqueças de aceitar a resposta :)

Comment: Não fazia ideia, sou novo no site, obrigado!